# How can i fetch and compare time of related post from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysql as database and saved time as time stamp of related posts in table, now i want to fetch the post made rrecently . How can i compare and fetch the post made recently?

Comment: This is a very basic query. I suggest you get yourself familiar with database interactions and query formation as it will help you in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can fetch rows in descending order of your column (time_stamp).
ex:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name ORDER BY col_time_stamp DESC;
```

col_time_stamp : is the column

Comment: `ORDER BY` clause is missing

Comment: @asprin thanks, i just missed it

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 * from posts order by timestamp desc
```

Comment: Will this work with a MySql database?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name ORDER BY col_time_stamp DESC LIMIT 0;
```